# List of all JavaFX JVM properties

Tags: java, javafx

When running a JavaFX application, I know I can pass some arguments to the JVM such as:

```
-Dcom.sun.javafx.touch=true 
-Dcom.sun.javafx.isEmbedded=true 
-Dcom.sun.javafx.virtualKeyboard=none
```

My question is: where can I find a list of all possible arguments?

Comment: I think there's still no official list. See https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8092282 There's also this very old Oracle forum discussion (which is where the feature request arose from): https://community.oracle.com/thread/2390862